# How can i make drawtext filter start the text scrolling from the center while scrolling from right to left

Tags: php, ffmpeg

Hello How can i make the text start from the center when the video play? Currently it start from the left side and people dont see the first words before it goes. I want the text to start from either the center of the video or the right while moving from right to left. Thanks in advance for helping me...
This is my code that currently works for the text, but it starts from the edge of the of the left while moving from right to left

```
echo shell_exec('ffmpeg -loop 1 -i slide2.jpg -vf scale=-2:1080,drawtext="textfile=text.txt:expansion=normal:fontfile=FreeSerif.otf: y=h-line_h-20:x=-200*t: fontcolor=white: fontsize=50" -pix_fmt yuv420p -t '.$words_count.' -movflags +faststart textover10.mp4 -report');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change expression for `x` to `x='-200*t+W/2'` The `W/2` sets initial position to horizontal center of image.

Comment: Hi @Mulvya, Thank you, it works well. Please can you teach me the ffmpeg tutorial, i want to know much about the package. Can we talk about that?

Comment: Hello The video is creating two line instead of one. Please what can i do?